# bxslider swiping only from carousel edge

Tags: bxslider, swipe-gesture

We have other instances of bxslider on our site with images instead of videos that behave as expected but this is our only instance of bxslider with embedded youtube videos.
The problem I am having is that I can only swipe through the carousel if I start my swipe on the very edge/frame of the carousel.
I have tried changing the swipeThreshold but that doesn't produce the result that I need it to.
What I want is to be able to swipe through the carousel regardless of where my swipe gesture starts in the carousel.

- What I think may be the problem is that the youtube touch controls are overriding the bxslider swipe events and thus not allowing swipe gestures to take place through the bxslider.

codepen.io/conc2304/pen/wGmgwM

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: http://codepen.io/conc2304/pen/wGmgwM @zer00ne